# VS2008 Team Edition Code Metrics - Skip Generated Code?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, metrics

According to [this](http://www.vitalygorn.com/blog/post/2007/11/Code-Metrics-in-Visual-Studio-2008.aspx) blog the build in code metrics feature in VS2008 Team Edition is suppose to be smart enough to skip generated code.  It's not.  Is there an option somewhere that I need to set?

Comment: **MUST NOT RANT ABOUT HOW MEANINGLESS CODE METRICS ARE**

Gahhh

Comment: Agree.  What I really want is a line count so instead of saying "project x is big", I can say "project X is 50,000 lines of custom code". Helps people visualize it better.

Comment: ...the metrics include line counts. Which is what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The real answer to this question is I gave up. :-) After messing with it a bit I got the distinct impression that the code metric feature was mostly a marketing stunt for Team System and nobody really invested in making it work well. I hope that changes in 2010--while metrics can be misused they can provide valuable insights as well.

Comment: P.s. Thanks for taking the time to comment on such an old question.  +1 vote!

Answer (score 1):

There are a few tags that affect this, depending on the source (MSDN/blogs/...)

- `CompilerGenerated`
- `ToolGenerated`
- `GeneratedCode`
- `DebuggerNonUserCode`

I'm not sure which of these works best in your case, but iirc I was able to get the metrics working right using one of these. Let me know how it worked out in your case.